# Show hover data for all subplots in plotly (R)

Tags: javascript, r, plotly

I have a function for plotting multiple y variables using a common shared x variable using subplots in Plotly for R. The issue I am having here is that the hover data does not show the y value for all plots; it displays only the graph where the mouse is hovered. In other words, I want to link all these graphs so that the y value for all graphs is displayed simultaneously. Here is the code and the output. The y values for variable a displayed; I would like to see the y value of variables b and c as well, simultaneously

```
 library(plotly)
 library(tidyverse)

plotly_stacked <- function(df, x_colName, cols){
      
      DF <- df[, cols] %>%
        tidyr::gather(variable, value, -x_colName ) %>%
        transform(id = as.integer(factor(variable)))
    
      DF$variable<- factor( DF$variable, levels = unique( DF$variable))
      
      p <- plot_ly(data = DF, x = ~get(names(DF[1])) , y = ~value, color = ~variable, colors = "Dark2",
                   yaxis = ~paste0( "y",sort(id, decreasing = F))) %>%
        
        add_lines() %>%
        layout(
         xaxis = list(
           title = ""), 
          legend = list(
                  orientation = "h",   
                  xanchor = "center",  
                  x = 0.5)) %>%
        plotly::subplot(nrows = length(unique(DF$variable)), shareX = TRUE)
      
      return(p)
    }
    
    df <- data.frame(
      Time = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,
               1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2),
      a = c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,
            0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18,
            0.19,0.2),
      b = c(0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.005,0.006,
            0.007,0.008,0.009,0.01,0.011,0.012,0.013,0.014,0.015,
            0.016,0.017,0.018,0.019,0.02),
      c = c(1e-04,2e-04,3e-04,4e-04,5e-04,6e-04,
            7e-04,8e-04,9e-04,0.001,0.0011,0.0012,0.0013,0.0014,
            0.0015,0.0016,0.0017,0.0018,0.0019,0.002)
    )
    
    plotly_stacked(df, "Time",  c( "Time" ,"a", "b", "c"))
```

[image: plotly subplot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use a custom event handler which can be applied to a plotly chart via `htmlwidgets::onRender`. See [part V of the plotly book](https://plotly-r.com/javascript) for an introduction.

```
library(plotly)

plotly_stacked(df, "Time", c("Time", "a", "b", "c")) |>
  htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el, x){el.on('plotly_hover', function(d) {
      var points = d.points[0], pointNum = points.pointNumber;
      Plotly.Fx.hover(el.id, [
        { curveNumber: 0, pointNumber: pointNum },
        { curveNumber: 1, pointNumber: pointNum },
        { curveNumber: 2, pointNumber: pointNum }],
        ['xy', 'xy2', 'xy3']
      );
    })}")
```

[image]

**EDIT** To show only the y value in the tooltip set `hovermode="x"` via `layout()` and adjust the custom event handler like so:

```
plotly_stacked(df, "Time", c("Time", "a", "b", "c")) |>
  layout(hovermode = "x") |>
  htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el, x){el.on('plotly_hover', function(d) {
      Plotly.Fx.hover(el.id,
        { xval: d.xvals[0] },
        ['xy', 'xy2', 'xy3']
      );
    })}")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, great , this works, I wanted to do one small change. Instead of showing (x,y) for all three graphs, I want to show only y vlaues for all graphs and one shared x value at the bottom. I tried to change  `add_lines(hovertemplate = "%{y}")`. It displays y values only now. For showing 1 common shared x value, should it be modified in the htmlwidgets?

Comment: After some research I figured out an option to achieve your desired result. See my edit.

Comment: Thats great! When using in Shiny, I have have arbitrary number of y variables. Is it possible to do something like this? 

`xy <- paste(
  c(paste0( "'", 'xy', "'"), sapply(2:3, function(x) paste0( "'", 'xy',x, "'")))
  , collapse = ",")

final_xy <- paste0("[",xy, "]")


plotly_stacked(df, "Time", c("Time", "a", "b", "c")) |>
  layout(hovermode = "x") |>
  htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el, x){el.on('plotly_hover', function(d) {
      Plotly.Fx.hover(el.id,
        { xval: d.xvals[0] },
        final_xy
      );
    })}")`

It doesnt work, maybe I need to use a diff method?

Comment: After doing some research, I was able to figure it out `# Create a vector of labels
      labels <- c("xy", paste0("xy", 2: length(input[[y]])))
   
      labels_json <- jsonlite::toJSON(labels)
      

      js_code <- sprintf(
        'function(el, x){el.on("plotly_hover", function(d) {
    Plotly.Fx.hover(el.id, {xval: d.xvals[0]}, %s);
  })}',
        labels_json
      )
      
           plotly_stacked (df =  data, x_colName = input[[x]] ,cols = c(input[[x]], input[[y]] ))|>
        layout(hovermode = "x") |>
        htmlwidgets::onRender(js_code)`